# How do I remove the tab provided by a third-party module?

Tags: routes

I'm using the [Guestbook](http://drupal.org/project/guestbook) module version 6x-2.0. How do I remove the "My Guestbook" tab on user profile pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with the [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering, hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs.
>
> Tab Tamer makes use of Drupal's drag ordering, but degrades gracefully when javascript is disabled.

Comment: if you solved the problem, you can mark this as accepted